# What is the name of this 5-pin connector?

Tags: identification, connector, pins

What kind of connector is in the images?

[image]   [image]

Comment: @ToddMinehardt didn't molex have 4 pins?

Comment: I stand corrected!

Comment: @ToddMinehardt  Molex connectors come in *many* different varieties; the vast majority have pin counts other than 4.

Comment: @toddminehardt I think you stand connected :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's a MATE-N-LOK connector

- Header: https://www.te.com/usa-en/product-640467-1.html (Mouser: 571-6404671)
- Plug: https://www.te.com/usa-en/product-1-480763-0.html (Mouser: 571-14807630)

Comment: Commonly these are known (slightly inaccurately) as Molex connectors. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molex_connector explains why. But MATE-N-LOK is technically the correct term.

Comment: @abligh How do you distinguish them? Are the original Molex connectors no longer in use? Wikipedia only writes "*The [Mate-n-Lok] connector was similar to the patented Molex connectors but not interchangeable. Both were widely used in the computer industry and the term "Molex connector" is often inaccurately used to refer to all nylon plugs and receptacles.*"

Comment: @Bergi I believe the original 1960s Molex connectors which predated and are not compatible with MATE-N-LOK are no longer used. I understand Molex's range now includes a range of connectors which are compatible with a subset of MATE-N-LOK (e.g. the 4x1 connector for 5.25" drives) - but there are plenty of MATE-N-LOK connector types Molex does not make. So calling them Molex is still (technically) wrong.

Answer (score 9):

I think it's the TE [MATE-N-LOK series](https://www.te.com/usa-en/products/brands/mate-n-lok.html). [Here's an example socket](https://www.te.com/usa-en/product-2213753-4.html) and [plug](https://www.te.com/usa-en/product-926299-5.html), though there's too many varieties to sort through to say if that's the exact one.